# connecting Mongodb to express. server not starting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mern

i am following a tutorial to learn MERN stack, i have routes and the other stuff in sepret files it works fine as shown in the first code below

```
dotenv.config()
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000

MongoClient.connect(
  process.env.REST_VIEW,
  {
    maxPoolSize:50,
    wtimeoutMS:2500,
    useNewUrlParser:true }
  )
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err.stack)
    process.exit(1)
  })
  .then(
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
    })
  )
```

but not like this, i don't get an error but the server doesn't start when i add the function with the "client" argument

```
.then(async (client) => {
   await RestaurantsDAO.injectDB(client)
   app.listen(port, () => {
     console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)
   })
 })
```

Comment: please provide error

Comment: like i said there is no error, but when i go to localhost:5000 there is nothing unless i remove that function